# Middle button does "back" in browser, how to disable?

Tags: mouse, kde

I'm using KDE and for some reason my middle mouse button activates "Back" in both Firefox and Chrome. I cannot find anything about those browsers to disable it, so presume it is some kind of global behaviour. How would I disable/change this behaviour?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/887873)?